# How to grant a group to another group in Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-redshift, roles

I have checked the Redshift documentation and It looks like it is possible to assign groups to user, but not to other groups.

Coming from different databases I was planning to have a matrix of groups with different permissions/priorities. Is this possible with Redshift?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Redshift is based on PostgreSQL. Neither system allows Groups within Groups.

Only **Users** can be added to **Groups**.

Comment: Postgres has the concept of roles, miss Italia NG in Redshift. To my knowledge Redshift is a rebranded Paraccel, another database only initially based on PG (and exposing the same api of that old PG)

Comment: Yes, Redshift was forked from Paraccel, so they share some common heritage but are quite different these days.

Comment: I know they are, but for some features Redshift is still stuck there, and comparing it with Postgres is misleading